# MacOS Anaconda Jupyter "name 'conda' is not defined"

Tags: python-3.x, installation, anaconda

After installing the Anaconda Package and launching the Jupyter notebook, something is wrong.

After typing:
conda --version

I get the message:

> ------------------------------------------------------- NameError   Traceback (most recent call last)  in
>   ()
>   ----> 1 conda --version
>
> NameError: name 'conda' is not defined
>
> ---

There is a lot of information about a similar message:
Conda: "command not found" error. 
It seems than the problem is related with the PATH.

Mine is the following and it seems OK:
/Users/VCF/anaconda/bin:/Users/VCF/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

But there is not information about the one I get:

> NameError: name 'conda' is not defined

I can't do anything with Jupyter

Does anyone help to solve this?

Comment: Aclarado. 
Conda is a Terminal comman, not a Jupyter - Python command